# Manipulate data from within a stream instead of opening two streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

so this is more a performance or best practice question.
I got a List that holds entries of a custom data structure. This looks like:

```
public class Entry {
    private int id;
    private String title;
    private String description;
    ....
}
```

So when I want to delete a entry from my list and append it to another list I do this:

```
Entry id = entries.stream().filter(e -> Integer.toString(e.getId()).equals(args[1]))
                  .map(e -> e).findAny().get();  

entries.stream().filter(e -> Integer.toString(e.getId()).equals(args[1]))
   .forEach(entry -> {
           doneEntries.add(new Entry(entry.getTitle(),   
                                     entry.getDescription(),
                                    "done",
                                     entry.getTags(), 
                                     doneId));
           doneId+=1;
    });
   entries.remove(id);
```

I know streams don't manipulate data they create new data so I cant't delete the entry in the second stream. It would cause a ConcurrentModificationException. In my opinion my result is just a workaround and is not very performant.

How to improve this code section?

Thank's in advance

Comment: Streams aren't always the best choice. I'm wondering why you're using them here at all instead of keeping your entries in a `Map` for example.

Comment: The answer given by [David](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4796021/david-pérez-cabrera) was good. But a map is definetly the best choice. Thank's to @Kayaman

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
entries = entries.stream().filter(e -> {
        boolean result = true;
        if (!Integer.toString(e.getId()).equals(args[1])) {
            doneEntries.add(new Entry(e.getTitle(), e.getDescription(), "done", e.getTags(), doneEntries.size() + 1));
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }).collect(Collectors.toList());
```